# Reset Counter Button In Android Action Bar

Tags: java, android

Building a small tap counter app. I would like the "refresh" button in the action bar to reset the textView reset back to zero.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub, refresh; // Tried to do this with refresh
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Amount: " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Amount: " + counter);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried several things and nothing

ActionBar Item

Comment: Not clear please post some code what you want

Comment: Thanks, I hit enter a tad too fast lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml layout (my_layout.xml):

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="reset counter"/>

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="5" />
```

In your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     //your counter variable
     int counter = 0;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

         final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  counter = 0;
                  textView.setText(counter+"");
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: You all are awesome, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

An activity populates the ActionBar in its onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

just override onCreateOptionsMenu like this:

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu.       
menu){

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

return true;
}
```

If an actions in the ActionBar is selected, the onOptionsItemSelected() method is called. It receives the selected action as parameter. Based on this information you code can decide what to do for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuitem1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        break;
    case R.id.menuitem2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can try this link if you don't know how to create action bar in your activity. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html